# Extracting the TBox Axioms from an Ontology using Python

Tags: python, owl, protege, rdflib, owlready

I am currently working on an algorithm for Descriptive Logics. I wanted to do try this project in Python, even though I am familiar with the strengths of OWL API in Java.

Currently I am stuck on accessing the TBox axioms in an ontology. I have looked into Owlready2, without finding a good solution; I can extract superclasses and subclasses.
I have checked RDFLibs extra module infixowl without any luck. Ive looked into OWLAPy, but it seems unfinished.

Any suggestions on libraries that let me import an ontology and extract the TBox axioms (positive insertions) such that I can access them in a loop?

Thanks!

Comment: you can loop over the different entities and get the correspoding content which makes up the logical axiom, e.g. for classes the sub/super classes, for properties the domain, range/characteristics etc.

Comment: @UninformedUser , Thanks for reply. I am familiar with getting sub/superclasses extracted with Owlready2 using someEntity.is_a and .subclasses, but how would you extract domains and ranges axioms?